# no SOAPAction header! in Oracle service bus

Tags: oracle, web-services, oracle-service-bus

I am facing below error in respose,

```
<faultcode      xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction</faultcode>
<faultstring>no SOAPAction header!</faultstring>
```

i am trying to fixing in pipeline ,

selected pass all headers through pipeline but didn’t helped[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKb7E.png)

Comment: Did you check wsdl, is there any SaopAction name set like  <soap:operation soapAction="xxxx"/>

Answer (score 0):

Do you *really* need a SoapAction?

One of the options available in a proxy is to decide which operation a SOAP message is, by inspecting the message body.

If someone sends a message (perhaps through a biz ref) and doesn't include a SOAP action header, a proxy will still recover if it uses this method.